# Creating Admin Plugin - Content of a page is displayed at global scope as well

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, admin-menu

I've started creating a WP plugin which should work only in Admin Area.

I've managed to create top-level menu with required sub-menu items, but when I try to print content of my page, it prints it twice, in a global scope of Admin panel and inside the page itself.

Main plugin file loads menu settings and separate page classes:
    require_once('settings.php');

```
require_once('pages/VmSettingsPage.php');
require_once('pages/VmTradersPage.php');

$settingsPage = new VmSettingsPage();
$tradersPage = new VmTradersPage();
```

Menu settings:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'cvmAdminMenu');
function cvmAdminMenu() {
    add_menu_page('VM Tool', 'VM Tool',
        'manage_options', 'camden-vmtool', ['VmSettingsPage','pageInit']);

    add_submenu_page('camden-vmtool', 'Traders Pages', 'Traders Pages', 'manage_options',
        'camden-vmtool-traders', ['VmTradersPage','pageInit']);
    add_submenu_page('camden-vmtool', 'Style Pages', 'Style Pages', 'manage_options',
        'camden-vmtool-style', 'cvmRenderStyle');
    add_submenu_page('camden-vmtool', 'Cat Navs', 'Cat Navs', 'manage_options',
        'camden-vmtool-cat-navs', 'cvmRenderCatnavs');
}
```

Settings Page class:

```
<?php

class VmSettingsPage {
    private $options;

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('admin_init', [$this, 'pageInit']);
    }

    public function pageInit() {
        echo 23123;
    }
}
```

Question #1 - The above code will output 23123 twice, when visiting plugin page and when not. How do I make it print the content of my page only when page is the current screen? Basically: http://localhost/wp-admin/admin.php?page=camden-vmtool

Question #2 - How to preload only one page class based on currently opened page? I will have around 4 pages, and It feels bad to load classes at once, just to have the class instance initiated.

BTW, get_current_screen's base parameter != $_GET['page'], so I cannot even match those to print correct content.

[image: Check the output]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question #1 - The above code will output 23123 twice, when visiting
>   plugin page and when not. How do I make it print the content of my
>   page only when page is the current screen? Basically:
>   `http://localhost/wp-admin/admin.php?page=camden-vmtool`

When you initialize the class, you are hooking the `pageInit()` method into a hook that fires on all admin pages. You are then specifically calling that method in your `add_menu_page()` arguments.

Honestly, I don't understand this one:

> Question #2 - How to preload only one page class based on currently
>   opened page? I will have around 4 pages, and It feels bad to load
>   classes at once, just to have the class instance initiated.

As to the first question, I don't know what `PageInit()` needs to do but given the limited information there is no need to instantiate the class beforehand. This works as is:

```
class VmSettingsPage {
    private $options;

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'pageInit'));
    }

    public function pageInit() {
        echo 23123;
    }
}
// $settingsPage = new VmSettingsPage();

add_action('admin_menu', 'cvmAdminMenu');
function cvmAdminMenu() {
    add_menu_page('VM Tool', 'VM Tool',
        'manage_options', 'camden-vmtool', array('VmSettingsPage','pageInit'));

}
```

The class will be instantiated automatically. If you do need to instantiate the class then your callback should be different:

```
class VmSettingsPage {
    private $options;

    public function __construct()
    {
//         add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'pageInit'));
    }

    public function pageInit() {
        echo 23123;
    }
}
global $settingsPage;
$settingsPage = new VmSettingsPage();

add_action('admin_menu', 'cvmAdminMenu');
function cvmAdminMenu() {
  global $settingsPage;
    add_menu_page('VM Tool', 'VM Tool',
        'manage_options', 'camden-vmtool', array($settingsPage,'pageInit'));
}
```

If you do that, then you can't use `admin_init` but there is no apparent reason to use that `admin_init` hook at all anyway.

I would further suggest that you encapsulate everything into your class:

```
class VmSettingsPage {
    private $options;

    public function __construct()
    {
//         add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'pageInit'));
      add_action('admin_menu', array($this,'cvmAdminMenu'));

    }

    function cvmAdminMenu() {
        add_menu_page('VM Tool', 'VM Tool',
            'manage_options', 'camden-vmtool', array($this,'pageInit'));
    }

    public function pageInit() {
        echo 23123;
    }
}
$settingsPage = new VmSettingsPage();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the job for Question #1. As for the #2, I just wanted to eliminate the need to require_once all 4 page classes at once (so they can be instantiated), instead I wanted to require only one class that is needed for the page I'm looking at